# href to downloadable url leads to page reload in flask app

Tags: html, ajax, flask, href

I have flask app and some href to url which downloads file(.log file),
I want to just download that file on click(button href leads to download on that url),
instead of opening new page, downloading, closing that page, and mainly refreshing
my main index.html? I don't want to force download, because there are situations where it will redirect to normal url( not downloadable one).

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `download` attribute to the `</a>` tag should download the file instantly without opening a new tab.

```html
<a href="/path/to/.log" download>
```

Comment: Ty, but I don't want to froce that, there are situations where that href is really link to another url :(

Comment: @PythonNewbie Check in JavaScript if the link is a direct download, if it is a downloadable URL do this: `element.setAttribute("download", "");`